# TypeError: builder.ChatConnector is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have a simple chat bot made in Node.js

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');

var botConnectorOptions = {
    appId: '',
    appPassword: ''
}

var connector = new builder.ChatConnector(botConnectorOptions); // error here
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

// waterfall method
bot.dialog('/',[
     function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session,'What is your name?');
    },
    function(session,args,next){
        session.send('Hello ' +args.response);
    }

 ]); 



// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();

// Handles the bot messages
server.post('/api/messages',connector.listen());

// serving a static web page
server.get('/.*/',restify.serveStatic({
    'directory': '.',
    'default': 'index.html'
}));

server.listen(process.env.port || 3978,function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});
```

Now, when I am trying to run this bot using Terminal in VS Code, it gives me the following error:

> TypeError: builder.ChatConnector is not a constructor

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet you are using is for the previous version of the Bot Framework (v3). You could install the previous version from npm to solve this issue, however my recommendation would be to [start with version 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/javascript/bot-builder-javascript-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

`npm install botbuilder@3.15.0`

> Microsoft Bot Framework SDK V4 was released in September 2018, and since then we have shipped a few dot-release improvements. As announced previously, the V3 SDK is being retired with final long-term support ending on December 31st, 2019. Accordingly, there will be no more development in this repo. Existing V3 bot workloads will continue to run without interruption. We have no plans to disrupt any running workloads.
>   [source](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3)

Comment: Oh! What a silly mistake.. I was unaware of the version and there you go.. Thank you so much! :)